# Does an Android app written with JavaScript for front end and Java for back end count as native?

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm really confused with what native means. I thought it referred to apps written completely in Java. I also heard that the top apps don't do hybrid development, they prefer native to stay advanced. However, I found that these guys use multiple languages for multiple different things. I'm new to coding and I have just finished learning JavaScript fundamentals and I am interested in developing Android apps. The native elitists have got me confused. Please guide me.

Comment: Native refers to the frontend (client) language. For example, a Java android app that sends requests to a Python backend server would still be native.

Answer (score 0):

"Native code" is code that the hardware can run directly, without a software translation layer.

For example, to run a JavaScript application you need an interpreter, and to run a Java application you need a JVM. Neither of them are native. In comparison, applications developed in C and C++ languages typically are native.

Most android applications are written in Java, and therefore are not native code. To add native code to an Android application you need to use NDK: https://developer.android.com/ndk